# checkbox with custom image not working on IE

Tags: jquery, css, forms, internet-explorer, checkbox

I have a checkbox with a custom image. It works, it's clickable, and it works on all browsers, except IE.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Here is the HTML of the checkbox, as generated by Typo3 and the Powermail-Plugin.

```
<label class="checked">
  <input type="hidden" name="tx_powermail_pi1[field][marker_20]" value="">
  <input data-parsley-errors-container=".powermail_field_error_container_marker_20" 
data-parsley-class-handler=".powermail_fieldwrap_marker_20 
div:first > div" class="powermail_checkbox 
powermail_checkbox_172" id="powermail_field_marker_20_1" 
type="checkbox" name="tx_powermail_pi1[field][marker_20][]" 
value="Ich habe die <f:link.page pageUid=&quot;45&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;>Datenschutzerklärung</f:link.page> verstanden." data-parsley-multiple="tx_powermail_pi1fieldmarker_20">
  Ich habe die <a target="_blank" href="/datenschutz">Datenschutzerklärung</a> verstanden.
</label>
```

And here is the jQuery that I am using to toggle it:

```
$(".tx-powermail input[type=checkbox]:checked").parent("label").addClass("checked");
        $(".tx-powermail input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
        $(this).parent("label").toggleClass("checked");
        });
```

It looks as if IE has problems with the hidden input field generated by Typo3. I have other checkboxes in other forms that lack that hidden input field so that the input type checkbox field is the label's first child element.

Comment: Do you need jquery - the point of having a label and input is that you can change it with css only.  Also is it valid to have tags inside attributes - shouldn't they be encoded?

Comment: I didn't make this jQuery but I think the reason is that there is a problem with the label being the parent element of everything.

Comment: can you not put the checkbox input before the label instead of inside it?

Comment: no, like I said I can not change the html-structure, the html is the way it is, generated by Typo3

Comment: ah well, anyway I think the problem may be  that ie is having issues with the tags inside your data attributes - you may need to html encode them

Comment: you mean this here?    value="Ich habe die <f:link.page pageUid=&quot;45&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;>Datenschutzerklärung</f:link.page> verstanden."

Comment: Did you try to make a test with IE after removing that? If yes, does it work with IE? also let us know if you are getting any warning or error message. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it myself, with help of this article: https://www.triplet.fi/blog/problem-solved-custom-checkbox-not-working-on-edge/

As you can see, I have no "for" attribute in my label.

So I edited the typo3 powermail template for checkboxes and added the "for". Now my checkboxes look like this:

```
<label class="checked" for="powermail_field_aktivmitglied_1">
```

This way it works in IE as well.